# Emacs doesn't load font at startup

Tags: fonts

I am using Emacs 26. Although in my init file i have the following

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "Noto Mono" :foundry "GOOG" :slant normal :weight normal :height 143 :width normal)))))
```

and also the font Noto Mono is installed on my Debian machine, Emacs doesn't load the font specification at startup. The font size and the font itself found above in my init file are not considered. Instead Emacs has much smaller Font size and the Monospace font.
I am using the Emacs GUI. 
Can any one help?

Comment: How do you start emacs?

Comment: Please clarify what concretely makes you think that "Emacs doesn't load the font specification".

Comment: @Stefan Because i am seeing another font and font size, in spite of having the above code in my init file!

Comment: @T.Verron I use the GUI

Comment: @Student: your answers should be reflected in the question (by editing the question) since the comments are not always visible.

Comment: Re-evaluate the custom settings (C-x C-e  with your cursor at the end of the form) after init just to be sure it has been loaded.

Comment: @RichieHH This works of course, but doesn't solve the problem!

Comment: What do you mean "of course"? By "it works" does this mean the font was correctly set?  In which case we know its not being loaded properly at init or you have somehow overriden it. You have called load custom-file? Silly I know but it pays to double check.